# Facebook Meta Tags

Tags: facebook

My problem was when some one is liking my website, the image, description, title etc. where completly wrong it took the first

which is the service level agreement in my website. So I figured I have to add opengraph meta tags so I did:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://url.com/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Web" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="My Web.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://url.com/logo.png" />
<meta property="og:description" content="My Web is a new community" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="7363627862327638" />
```

The problem is, it is still not working, the likes information is wrong, and I waited atleast 72 hours, so the cache of Facebook is not the problem.

Does anyone know what could be the problem? Thanks alot already!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Checkout [this..](http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags) tutorial.

and use [facebook debug tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to clear cache and set new metatags for your page.

Comment: Problem is, I cleared the cache and I'm 100% sure its in the source code exactly how Facebook wants them formatted. Very strange :S

Comment: Thanks for the facebook debug tool link! This solved my issue very quickly!

Answer (score 2):

**Try this it worked for me** -
Use Dynamic content in meta tag.

```
<?php

$params = array();
if(count($_GET) > 0) {
    $params = $_GET;
} else {
    $params = $_POST;
}
// defaults
if($params['type'] == "") $params['type'] = "restaurant";
if($params['locale'] == "") $params['locale'] = "en_US";
if($params['title'] == "") $params['title'] = "default title";
if($params['image'] == "") $params['image'] = "thumb";
if($params['description'] == "") $params['description'] = "default description";

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# MY_APP_NAME_SPACE: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/MY_APP_NAME_SPACE#">
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

        <!-- Open Graph meta tags -->
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="MY_APP_ID" />
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="meta site name"/>
        <meta property="og:url" content="URL?type=<?php echo $params['type']; ?>&locale=<?php echo $params['locale']; ?>&title=<?php echo $params['title']; ?>&image=<?php echo $params['image']; ?>&description=<?php echo $params['description']; ?>"/>
        <meta property="og:type" content="MY_APP_NAME_SPACE:<?php echo $params['type']; ?>"/>
        <meta property="og:locale" content="<?php echo $params['locale']; ?>"/>
        <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $params['title']; ?>"/>
        <meta property="og:image" content="URL<?php echo $params['image']; ?>.png"/>
        <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $params['description']; ?>"/>

    </head>
</html>
```